# multer saves image in a weird format

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to serve an image from my Express server to my client but multer is saving the file in a weird format which leads to issues when my react app tries to render the image

multer server side code:

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        // accept a file
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        // reject a file
        cb(new Error('Incorrect file'), false);
    }
}
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // max 5mb for image size
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

router.post('/', upload.single('productImage'), ProductsController.products_create_product);
```

This code successfully creates the file in the `/uploads` folder but when I save the path to the database I get this response:

Postman

```
{
    "size": 5,
    "quantityInStock": 11,
    "productImage": "uploads\\2021-03-11T19-18-05.442Zvans-2.jpg",
}
```

How can I change it so it saves the image in this format: `/uploads/2021-03-11T19-18-05.442Zvans-2.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fix your destination path like  this:

```
cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './uploads/'));
```

For me this was the full code-block. Just grab the actual part you want:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const appConfigs =  require('./../config/app');

module.exports = function (folderName) {
    // TODO: console log here and optimize multiple initialization of multer if need
    return multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './../uploads/' + folderName);
                cb(null, filePath);
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
                const fileName = (new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0) + '.' + extension;
                cb(null, fileName);
            }
        }),
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * appConfigs.image_max_size // MB
        },
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            let valid = (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png');
            cb(null, valid);
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: should i save my images in the server or do something like `../../client/public/images` and save the path to that and then try to render the image by passing that to the `src` attribute?

Comment: It's up to you. There is many solutions. 1. If you planning to save all the images in one directory, then you can just keep the image filename in the DB (e.g. "fileLongUniqueName.jpg"). In my example I just did like that

Comment: 2. Sometimes need to save a lot of files in the server, so in that case I would suggest you to keep them in separated folders depended from current date, so you need to develop that functionality to create some folders manually in the time of uploading (e.g. "2021/03/12/fileLongUniqueName.jpg").

Comment: 3. If you planning to use external storage for future, the I would suggest you to save the image public URL (you can save image path as well if you'll need later) in the DB, so the images can have different URLs like local "https://site-domain/some-uri/fileLongUniqueName.jpg" or external "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/folder-name/fileLongUniqueName.jpg", etc.

Comment: [this article](https://dev.to/therealdanvega/creating-multiple-directories-in-node-37c6)  might be useful for you (for 2-nd case)

Comment: alright sweet thank you, i'll read that article in a sec but for now I plan on taking the 1st approach and just save all the image files in one directory in the backend and make that statically available to the frontend.

Comment: I tried your answer but it gave me an error `__dirname is not defined` - so i created a constant `const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''));` but now it saved the file path in the db like `c\\....\\....\\.....\\....\\...\\server\\uploads\\1615550321141.jpg`